# AR overlays on newspapers

Tags: vuforia

Creating an AR application using Vuforia SDK in Unity 3D to recognize a newspaper, identify images and text, trigger a custom search, and display related content as AR overlays onto the newspaper

I have tried but , im out of ideas

Comment: "*I have tried but*" - Please add your attempts inside the question then - [ask]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.